# Logging in via SSH to a Linux host via ssh key always fails on first try, tnen works. Is there some configurable timeout?

Tags: linux

I have created **ssh keys** and registered my public key on the target host under `.ssh/.authorized_keys`.

And it also generally works. I just observe a strange behavior: When I try to login the first time in the morning, I see `"Server refused our key"` and get forced to enter my passphrase. Any consecutive attempts then work fine and I see in the console output that it's registering with my key.

If I don't log in for a longer time, then a new login would show the same behavior as above and I get forced to enter my passphrase.

So I was wondering: Is there maybe a configurable value that prevents me registering with my key after certain time that I can just increase or deactivate?

Comment: Some hosting providers do weird MITM things to SSH, there's a write-up somewhere ...

Comment: Because you didn't give enough information about your problem to *solve* it, only to *guess* what might help. -1 isn't anything to really worry about, just edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer here. Some servers are configured to verify the hosts before they can login for the first time. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42643/ssh-key-based-authentication-known-hosts-vs-authorized-keys

We can make SSH automatically write new host keys to the known_hosts file by setting **StrictHostKeyChecking** to “no” in the **~/.ssh/config** file.

```
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Comment: Thanks, added this config. But that doesn't have any impact on the behavior.